# How to select data from 1 database, insert into another and insert also new data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to select the data from 1 database and insert it into another database. I also got a working code for this:

> INSERT INTO db2.users (steamid, name) SELECT steamid, nickname FROM db1.ttt_stats WHERE steamid NOT IN (SELECT steamid FROM db2.users)

And now I want also to insert new data (like group) into the new database with this here:

> INSERT INTO db2.users (steamid, name, group) SELECT steamid, nickname, 'newgroup' FROM db1.ttt_stats WHERE steamid NOT IN (SELECT steamid FROM db2.users)

But there is always an Syntax error. I also googled alot, and this should be the working code, but its not working... And yes the row "group" exists in the second database.

I also tried it with VALUES, which is also not working:

> INSERT INTO db2.users (steamid, name, group) VALUES (SELECT steamid, nickname, 'newgroup' FROM db1.ttt_stats WHERE steamid NOT IN (SELECT steamid FROM db2.users))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using backticks...

```
INSERT INTO db2.users (steamid, name,`group`) SELECT steamid, nickname FROM db1.ttt_stats WHERE steamid NOT IN (SELECT steamid FROM db2.users)
```

Take a look at [reserved keywords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-1.html) in MySQL, group is one of them.

Comment: Ah, yes you are right. It is a reserved keyword. Now its working. Thank you :)

Comment: I am glad to hear that. If this answer solved your issue, please mark it as accepted...And welcome to StackOverflow!